# empty cell in the column should replace with current date in python

Tags: python

I have a problem that i have a date/time column in which some of the columns are empty then i want to replace that 
empty cell with todays date how it will work the same code i have written down please help with this.......
**please note that i'm using Pandas Dataframe so please answer should not contain any dataframe..thanks**

```
with open(tempFile, 'r',encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        # creating a csv reader object 
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    #     next(reader, None)

        '''We then restructure the data to be a set of keys with list of values {key_1: [], key_2: []}:'''        
        data = {}
        for row in reader:
    #         print(row)
            for header, value in row.items():
                try:
                    data[header].append(value)
                except KeyError:
                    data[header] = [value]

        '''Next we want to give each value in each list a unique identifier.'''            
        # Loop through all keys
        for key in data.keys():
            values = data[key]

            things = list(sorted(set(values), key=values.index))

            for i, x in enumerate(data[key]):

                if key==("Date/Time") :
                    data[key][i] = data[key][i][0:10]
                else:
                    data[key][i] = things.index(x) + 1

    """Since csv.writerows() takes a list but treats it as a row, we need to restructure our 
        data so that each row is one value from each list. This can be accomplished using zip():"""

    with open('ram5.csv', "w") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        # Write headers
        writer.writerow(data.keys())
        # Make one row equal to one value from each list
        rows = zip(*data.values())
        # Write rows
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

**This code do other operations also please only focus on date and time column..**
the input data is :

```
job_Id      Name        Address     Email            Date/Time
1        snehil singh   marathalli  ss@gmail.com     12/10/2011:02:03:20
2        salman         marathalli  ss@gmail.com     12/11/2011:03:10:20
3        Amir           HSR         ar@gmail.com    
4        Rakhesh        HSR         rakesh@gmail.com 09/12/2010:02:03:55
5        Ram            marathalli  r@gmail.com 
6        Shyam          BTM         ss@gmail.com     12/11/2012:01:03:20
7        salman         HSR         ss@gmail.com    
8        Amir           BTM         ar@gmail.com     07/10/2013:04:02:30
9        snehil singh   Majestic    sne@gmail.com    03/03/2018:02:03:20
```

The empty date/time column should be replaced with current date...
I have tried to put between the code...but it does't work please hep me...thanks

```
if["Date/Time"]==None:
                    data[key][i]="11/12/2018"
                else:
                    data[key][i] = data[key][i][0:10]
                    continue
```

**my Code wroked with this way:**

```
if data[key][i] == "":
   data[key][i] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
```

thnx evryone for help

Comment: what is "Post Until" key here, also I think the values are not None , they will be empty string

Comment: srry  that was a mistake now it is edited

Answer (score 0):

You can select the empty cells of a column using .loc and .isnull(), and you can get the current time with the datetime library.
It should work altogether like this:

```
import datetime
data.loc[data['Date/Time'].isnull(), 'Date/Time'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Sir i'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: That's because data is a dictionary and not a dataframe. Replace "data" by the name of the dataframe which has the values you want to replace.

Comment: i didn't use any data frame in my code please see in my code tell where should i add this line i don't anything about dataframe i'm new to python.. please help me

Comment: Can you add your data  in question, it will help us to find solution

Comment: i have given full input data in my code please see above

Comment: What is the error you are getting with your original attempt?

Comment: got it with this way :     if data[key][i] == "":
                data[key][i] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for each in data:
    if not each['Date/Time']:
       each['Date/Time']=datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: i'm getting a error :TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: In which line you are adding this code, also you are given the input data like dataframe, can you give the dict data that you are trying to change ?

Comment: i'm adding it the for loop in this: for i, x in enumerate(data[key]): actually i'm not getting where to add